# JavaScript Closures calculate sum

Tags: javascript, closures

I just started learning closures in JavaScript and I'm trying to understand a basic problem.

For example, I'm trying to implement the sum method: `sum(1)(4)(5)`

```
const sum = (a) => {
    return (b) => {
        if(typeof b === 'number')
            return sum(a+b)
        return a;
    }
}
```

When I call: `console.log(sum(1)(4)(5)())` it works perfect and return 10. However, if I call `console.log(sum(1)(4)(5))`, it returns `[Function (anonymous)]`. Why?

Thanks

Comment: in sum(1)(4)(5)() the last call causes if statement to be skipped and `return a` to be executed. However when you keep passing numbers into the function it goes into `return sum(a+b)` which then returns a new clojure

Comment: Because functions return different things when called differently

Comment: Btw when  the intent is to implement a function which can take any amount of arguments like above, it becomes necessary to mark the end of the arguments. Which you do by the last empty call.  So I don't think you can get rid of that last call.

Comment: @AliBaykal are you saying that there is no what to make it work without inserting the last parenthesis

Comment: @user2792523, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call your function like:

```
sum(1)(10)
```

you are returning the inner function:

```
(b) => {
        if(typeof b === 'number')
            return sum(a+b)
        return a;
    }
```

Because type of b === 'number' and you are returning sum(a+b) that calls
again the function sum and returns again the inner function. Thats why when you finally put the last parenthesis like:

```
sum(1)(10)()
```

The inner function will execute and type of b in this case is different from number and will return 'a' that already contains the sum of the values.

Comment: I know it. My question is, how can I make it work without inserting the last parenthesis

Comment: @user2792523 You can't, really. You have to return another function, to make another call with a number possible.